# Javascript - Add business days to a user selected date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I need to add user defined business days to a user defined date and for it to display in an alert box.

Could you please look at my code and let me know what needs changing:

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bZXH/)

```
Select Business Days To Add<br>
<select name="coll" id="t1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><p>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>  $(function() {    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); }); </script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="alert()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start write a function that takes the selected date and days:

```
<center>Select Business Days To Add<br>
<select name="coll" id="t1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><p>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>  $(function() {    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); });
    function getSelectedDate() {
           var day = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");     
           var daysToAdd = $("#t1").val();
           return Number(daysToAdd) + Number(day.getDate());
        }
    </script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="alert(getSelectedDate());"/>
```

I suppose business days mean from monday to friday, so adding 1 to friday would mean actually monday and not saturday.

Further

- you need to look if the current day is friday and add two days to the
  selected business days to jump over the weekend - use [getDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp)
- if it is end of the month (regarding even and uneven months 30 and 31
  days and february on leap and not leap year) and if needed increment
  the month too - use [getMonth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)
- if it is end of the year, increment the year - use [getFullYear](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp)

The code (**without the check for weekends**) looks like this:

```
<center>Select Business Days To Add<br>
<select name="coll" id="t1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><p>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>  $(function() {    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); });

        function isEndOfMonth(date) {
        // day of month from 1 to 31
        var selectedDay = date.getDate();
        // months with 31 days
        if (date.getMonth() == 0 || date.getMonth() == 2 || 
            date.getMonth() == 4 || date.getMonth() == 6 || 
            date.getMonth() == 7 || date.getMonth() == 9 || 
            date.getMonth() == 11) {
            return selectedDay == 31;
        }
        // february 28 / 29 days TODO check for leap year!
        if (date.getMonth() == 1) { return selectedDay == 28; }

        // months with 30 days
        if (date.getMonth() == 3 || date.getMonth() == 5 || 
            date.getMonth() == 8 || date.getMonth() == 10) {
            return selectedDay == 30;
        }
            return false;
        }

        function isEndOfYear(month) {
            return month > 11;
        }

        function getSelectedDate() {
           var day = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

           var daysToAdd = Number($("#t1").val());
           // values from which the new date is constructed
           var selectedMonth = day.getMonth();
           var selectedYear = day.getFullYear();
           var selectedDay = day.getDate();
           // 
           if (isEndOfMonth(day)) {
               // start new month
               selectedDay = 1;
               selectedMonth++;
               if (isEndOfYear(selectedMonth)) {
                   // start new year
                   selectedYear++;
               }
           }
            // add business days
            selectedDay += daysToAdd;
            // TODO check if the result is weekend and jump over it. After a jump the same checks as above should be called!
            return new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    </script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="alert(getSelectedDate());"/>
```

If for example the selected date is *14.Oct.2013*, selected days *2*, the function yields *16.Oct.2013*.