# How to get the correct day?

Tags: javascript, date, time, schedule

any idea how could I make what for 6 days a system which  knows the date can make me to display some info depending on what is the actual date. EX: Day 1 : Info Day2: Info 2, but I do not know how can I make what the system knew what today is 5 and tomorrow will be 6 and then will be 1 and like this way again to 6. Not counting sunday and saturday.

The thing is what today is day 5 but tomorrow will be day 6. Example: It depends on the day if it will be day 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 the Monday can be day 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 depending. I want a way to count the day with the date. Today Feb 18 is day 5 so which day will be EX: 26 of Feb?.

For now I have this in my code but I'm stuck:

```
//Definiendo Fecha
var hoy = new Date();
var dd = hoy.getDate();
var mm = hoy.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = hoy.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = "0" + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = "0" + mm;
}

hoy = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
//Fin
document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML = hoy;
contador = 4
function obtenerDia() {
  if (!(hoy = "17/02/2019")) {
    contador++
  }else {
    console.log("Algo pasa.")
  }
}
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Context:
I'm building an schedule, so it should display the correct schedule of the day when it is EX: The day 1 ... 5 , depending on which day is the correct one.

Comment: Why does your week have only 6 days where everyone else's has 7? Asked another way: on what date does this 6-day cycle begin?

Comment: Note also that it should likely be `if (hoy !== "17/02/2019")`

Comment: @HereticMonkey—the integers aren't days of the week, they're just a sequence that can start on any day and skip Sat and Sun, e.g. if 1 is Tue, then 6 is the following Tue.

Comment: Providing you know one of the dates and the day index it belongs to, you can work out the other dates simply by stepping forward or backward over the dates and testing the day number to skip Sat and Sun. Fairly basic and likely not optimal for performance, but if there's only a maximum of 5 steps it's not an issue. But you need to provide a bit more context about the input and expected output.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [*Javascript - Add business days to a user selected date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282371/javascript-add-business-days-to-a-user-selected-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|170.4769) or [*Finding date and adding specific number of business days to it*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274040/finding-date-and-adding-specific-number-of-business-days-to-it?r=SearchResults&s=2|81.9849) or even [*add day (Businessday Only)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198187/add-day-businessday-only/35200701?r=SearchResults&s=3|70.0973#35200701).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generalized solution, consider:

```js
function getDayNumber(baseDate, targetDate, daysInCycle) {
    var startOfBaseDate = new Date(baseDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var startOfTargetDate = new Date(targetDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var differenceInDays = Math.round((startOfTargetDate - startOfBaseDate) / 864e5);
    return ((differenceInDays % daysInCycle + daysInCycle) % daysInCycle) + 1;
}
```

- The `baseDate` is any `Date` object (or timestamp) that corresponds to "Day 1" of the cycle.
- The `targetDate` is the `Date` object (or timestamp) you wish to find the day number for.
- The `daysInCycle` is the number of days before the cycle repeats, such as `6` for a six day cycle.

Examples:

```js
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 15), 6)  //=> 4
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 16), 6)  //=> 5
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 17), 6)  //=> 6
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 18), 6)  //=> 1
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 19), 6)  //=> 2
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 20), 6)  //=> 3
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 21), 6)  //=> 4
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 22), 6)  //=> 5
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 23), 6)  //=> 6
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 24), 6)  //=> 1
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 25), 6)  //=> 2
getDayNumber(new Date(2019, 1, 18), new Date(2019, 1, 26), 6)  //=> 3
```

For `baseDate` or `targetDate`, you could pass `Date.UTC(2019, 1, 18)` if you wanted to use the UTC day as a basis.

For `targetDate`, you can pass either `new Date()` or `Date.now()` to use the current timestamp.

Note also that the last line of the function uses the modulo solution given [here](https://dev.to/maurobringolf/a-neat-trick-to-compute-modulo-of-negative-numbers-111e) in order to ensure that negative numbers (dates before the base date) are handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the general solution.

Comment: @Santiago - If this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted and upvote.  Thanks.